# Can i able to use touch using dispatchTouchEvent for particular layout?

Tags: android, touch, ontouchlistener

I'm using two different layouts in my activity where in one activity i need to work with touch screen and in another activity it should not work on Touch screen.

How i can do it?

I tried to used dispatchTouchEvent to get the touch response but it gets for the entire activity, is there any way to get based on the layout ?

I used

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    .
    .
    .
    return true;
}
```

if i used like this it disables all the touch event in my activity.

Comment: `"I'm using two different layouts in my activity"`, how?

Comment: <RelativeLayout
.
.<RelativeLayout  // 1st layout
.
.
.
 />
.<RelativeLayout  //2nd layout
.
.
.
/>
.
/>

Comment: so you have nested `RelativeLayout`s right? if so how do you handle your touch events? by calling `View#setOnTouchListener`? post your code

Comment: @Override
   public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
       .
       .
       .
        return true;
    }

Comment: no, it is used to intercept all touch screen events before they are dispatched to the window

Comment: yes thats how it works, but what i want is to Intercept all touch event only for the nested layout alone.

Comment: RelativeLayout leg_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.leg_plain);
        //leg_layout.setEnabled(false);
        leg_layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                    // Do what you want
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

it is correct ?
it didnt work.